# How to detect when at the bottom of a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a website that loads data as you scroll down. Every time you hit the bottom of the page, it loads another 100 rows. I'm trying to replicate this in a div so that the header is always at the top no matter how far you scroll down.

I'm using JQuery and the scrollTop() function to do this.

Here is my code that works if it is not detecting the scroll bar in the div, but the whole window.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
            for(i; i < size+100; i++){
                document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML += IPAMArray[i];
            }
            size = i;

    }
});
```

Now i change the div to this:

```
<div class = "tableDiv" id="myTableDiv" style="height:800px;width:1000px;border:1px solid #ccc; overflow: scroll;"><table id = "myTable"></table></div>
```

I dont know how to change this line from "document" and "window" to the correct div variables:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
```

Here is where i'm currently at with that line:

```
if ($("div.tableDiv").scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $("div.tableDiv").height()){
```

I've tried quite a few variants, but i'm completely guessing the code so it could take forever. I would prefer to refer to this div by its ID rather than its class, but i just started using the class references because thats how most of the examples are online. I have tried $(document).getElementById('myTableDiv') in various ways as well but cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: I think you are trying to bite off more than you can chew. If you don't have a solid grasp of JavaScript and jQuery prior to taking on a project like this, you will be struggling through every part of the process. I would highly recommend completing some beginner tutorials on JavaScript/jQuery before attempting something like this. Just my two cents; I think you are trying to learn this the hard way :\

Comment: @Jason Hey now, i'm insulted. This is a pretty specific javascript reference.

Comment: I did not intend to offend you with my suggestion. Based on your question, it appeared to me that you were not feeling confident with your JavaScript skills (e.g. "i'm completely guessing the code so it could take forever"). If you weren't sure how to target IDs using jQuery, I would imagine you haven't spent much time with it. My comment was not one of condescension.

Comment: @Jason I gotcha, i've spent the last couple weeks using javascript with ember.js development so i am very rusty in creating generic web pages. I also dont really use Jquery too much. So you're probably right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($("#myTableDiv").scrollTop() == $("#myTable").outherHeight() - $("#myTableDiv").height()){
```

1. use ids to identify elements
2. the height of the inner element is what you need (`$("#myTable").height()`)
3. jquery's `height()` function doesn't include borders margins and / or paddings as noted in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/height/). Use [outherHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) instead.

OR

make your header `position: fixed` in css

Comment: That doesnt seem to be working. I also changed the top function to "$("#myTableDiv").scroll(function(){

Comment: #myTableDiv is locked as 800 and #myTableDiv is initially 2680 and that wont change. It will never become equal

Comment: You use a div inside of a div. For some reason my Table is 18 pixels short. If i do if($("#myTableDiv").scrollTop() == $("#myTable").height() - $("#myTableDiv").height() +18){ then it works.

Comment: hmmm... jquery's `height()` function doesn't include borders margins and / or paddings as noted in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/height/). [outherHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) is what you need